# No multiples in Pythagorean triplets

Tags: matlab, octave

Based on the book Physical Modeling in Matlab (available online [here](http://greenteapress.com/wp/physical-modeling-in-matlab-2e/)) I have the following functions to find Pythagorean triplets

```
# Function isintegral. Checks whether a number is integer

function res = isintegral(x)
    if round(x) == x
        res = 1;
    else
        res = 0;
    end
end

# function hypotenuse computes the length 
# of the hypotenuse of a right triangle if 
# the lengths of the adjacent sides are a and b

function res = hypotenuse(a,b)
res = sqrt(a^2+b^2);
end

# function find_triples
# A function to search for “Pythagorean triples”

function res = find_triples (n)
    for a = 1:n
        for b = a:n 
            c = hypotenuse(a,b);
            flag = isintegral(c);
            if flag
                [a,b,c]
            end
        end
    end
end
```

In this way

```
>> find_triples(15)
ans =

   3   4   5

ans =

    5   12   13

ans =

    6    8   10

ans =

    8   15   17

ans =

    9   12   15
```

Apart from the triples 5, 12, 13 and 8, 15, 17 the others are just multiples of the 3, 4, 5 triangle. So how can one modify the code so that it returns only `[3,4,5]`, `[5,12,13]`, `[8,15,17]` if we execute `find_triples(15)` ?

Comment: You can compute the greatest common divisor of `a,b,c` if it is 1 print the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using @rahema's suggestion, your program becomes short and simple:

```
table = [];
for a = 1:n
    for b = a:n
        c = sqrt(a^2+b^2);
        flag = round(c) == c && gcd(a,b)==1;
        if flag
            table = [table; a,b,c];
        end
    end
end
```

and it runs smoothly, and it finds the triples without the multiples.

However, the calculation can be done a lot more efficiently, using

```
i = kron(ones((n+1)/2,1),[1:2:n]');
j = kron([1:2:n]',ones((n+1)/2,1));

isok = i>j & gcd(i,j)==1;
i = i(isok);
j = j(isok);

a = i .* j;
b = (i.^2-j.^2)/2;
c = (i.^2+j.^2)/2;

table2 = [min(a,b),max(a,b),c];
```

I ran both programs in Octave for various numbers of n (30, 60, 120, 240, 480
and 960) and found the following results:

```
Method 1: found 5 triples in 0.0207 seconds
Method 2: found 91 triples in 0.0014 seconds
The first 5 triples are the same

Method 1: found 11 triples in 0.0723 seconds
Method 2: found 364 triples in 0.0016 seconds
The first 8 triples are the same

Method 1: found 22 triples in 0.2724 seconds
Method 2: found 1455 triples in 0.0022 seconds
The first 11 triples are the same

Method 1: found 42 triples in 1.0705 seconds
Method 2: found 5841 triples in 0.0052 seconds
The first 16 triples are the same

Method 1: found 88 triples in 4.2629 seconds
Method 2: found 23357 triples in 0.0201 seconds
The first 25 triples are the same

Method 1: found 173 triples in 16.9313 seconds
Method 2: found 93337 triples in 0.0970 seconds
The first 25 triples are the same
```